# Compiler warning about large atomic operation

Tags: c, gcc, clang, atomic

The following code generate a compiler warning when running in Clang but emits no warnings in GCC.

> #1 with x86-64 clang (trunk) :29:13: warning: large atomic operation may incur significant performance penalty
> [-Watomic-alignment]
>
> } while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(r, &e, updated));

GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/Q5WAni

```
typedef struct reference {
  void *address;
  size_t usages;
} reference_t;
_Static_assert(sizeof(reference_t) == 16, "Must be 16");


bool reference_inc(_Atomic(reference_t )*r) {
    
  reference_t updated,e ;
  do {
    reference_t e = *r;
    reference_t updated = e;
    updated.usages++;
  } while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(r, &e, updated));
  return  true;
}
```

Looking at the assembly code, GCC emits: `__atomic_compare_exchange_16` and Clang outputs:

```
    mov     edi, 16
    mov     rsi, rbx
    mov     rdx, r15
    mov     rcx, r12
    mov     r8d, 5
    mov     r9d, 5
    call    __atomic_compare_exchange
```

I am actually trying to convince the compilers to emit a `lock cmpxchg16b`, but that seems like it won't be successful.

I'm trying to figure out if I should ignore this warning or not.

Comment: I think you have to `_Alignas(16)` at least. [Looks like a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80878#c20).

Comment: I tried `typedef struct reference {
  alignas(16) void *address;
  size_t usages;
} reference_t;`

But I still get the warning

Comment: This is a much discussed topic - there are at least two tickets: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84522 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80878